# undefined reference to constructor for argument

Tags: c++, constructor, undefined-reference

Good evening

I have a small problem with a constructor. I'm trying to build a tree of the different possible plays of my board (to do a DepthFirstSearch after). In my node class constructor, i want to copy the current board as a leaf for the tree. But i got an error "undefined reference to `Board::Board()'|" when i try to use my Board class instance as an argument for Node constructor.

If you have an idea of how to do this correctly, i'm listening, i really don't see any problem :(

Here is my class node :

```
class Node
{
private :
    Board      state;
    list<Node>  sons;
public :
                Node(Board&);
    void        addNode(Board&);
};
```

While doing the Node constructor, i do this :

```
Node::Node(Board& tab)
{
    state = tab;
    sons = NULL;
}
```

My Board class is :

```
class Board {

private :
    int**           tab;
    int             nbline;
    int             nbcolumn;
    Position        emptyspot;

public  :
                    Board(int, int, Play&); // initialised with random positions
                    Board(int, int); // just the good size, no values inside. Node::node during constructor.
    void            setValue(Position&, int);
    void            setNbline(int m);
    void            setNbcolumn(int n);
    int             getValue(Position&);
    int             getNbline();
    int             getNbcolumn();
    int             getEmptyline();
    int             getEmptycolumn();
    void            setEmptySpot(Position&);
    Position&       getEmptySpot();

    Board&          operator=(Board& source);
};
```

EDIT : Due to people asking, here are the constructors of Board:

```
    Board::Board(int m, int n, Play& jeu) : tab{new int*[m]}, nbline{m}, nbcolumn{n}, emptyspot{n-1,m-1}{

       int              x(1);

       for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
            tab[i] = new int[n];

            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                tab[i][j] = x; x++;}}

       tab[n-1][m-1]=0;
       x=0;

       while (x!=1000)
       {
        int numbers[] = { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
        int length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(int);
        int randomNumber = numbers[rand() % length];

        jeu.moves(*this, randomNumber);
        x++;
       }
    }

    Board::Board(int m, int n) : tab{new int*[m]}, nbline{m}, nbcolumn{n}, emptyspot{n-1,m-1}  {
      for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        tab[i] = new int[n];

        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            tab[i][j] = 0;}}
}
```

Comment: It's strange that you have an assignment operator but no copy constructor.

Comment: Are you defining the constructor for `Board`? You just listed the declarations.

Comment: You mean that i should have a constructor in board that copy an existing instance of Board to a new one ? :o :o :o How ?

Comment: Ideally you should design your class so that its default-generated copy constructor and assignment operator will work. I don't know if that's the case as I don't know what your constructors are doing. Hopefully nothing with `new` in it. You will need a properly working copy constructor for my solution to work.

Comment: Don't use news and pointers! Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(ysize, std::vector<int>(xsize))` which can be used as `matrix[y][x]`. Then your class won't leak memory and you don't need to provide the copy constructor or assignment operator. It will just work.

Comment: I will. As soon as the DFS is coded and working, i'll change it to matix ! Thx !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not strange. In `Node::Node(Board& tab)` state is default-initialized before you make an assignment. Since you doesn't do it explicitly, compiler calls `Board::Board()`, which is not defined. Change `Node::Node()` to:

```
Node::Node(Board& tab)
: state(tab)
, sons(NULL)
{
}
```

Remember, it is required, that all members must be fully-initialized before body of the constructor gets executed. So classes containing reference members or instances of classes, that do not have default/copy constructor defined, always must initialize them via initialization list.

Also, if you have defined `operator=()` in `Board`, define also copy constructor (rememeber about [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)):

```
class Board
{
//...

  Board(const Board&)
  {
    //make a copy
  }

};
```

**EDIT**

I think Board's copy constructor should be implemented this way:

```
Board(const Board& origin)
: tab(NULL)
, nbline(origin.nbline)
, nbcolumn(origin.nbcolumn)
, emptyspot(origin.emptyspot)
{
  this->tab = new int*[this->nbline];

  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    this->tab[i] = new int[this->nbcolumn];

  //Tab contains int's, so let's do simple memcpy()
  memcpy(this->tab, origin.tab, sizeof(int) * this->nbline * this->nbcolumn);
}
```

Comment: Is this the right copy constructor ? Or am I wrong ?
Board::Board(const Board& other) : tab(other.tab), nbline(other.nbline), nbcolumn(other.nbcolumn), emptyspot(other.emptyspot) {}

Comment: No, you cannot copy tab via simple assignment, because you would free the same resource more than once. I will update my answer with proper implementation.

Comment: Why would it free the same ressource several time ?? é-è   
An update with a proper implementation would help me a lot. I barely heared of copy constructor so i'm a bit lost :( I'll be able to create my own copy constructors for my other classes with the help of your update, to see if I understood it well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If i understood it well, my class position should have a copy constructor too since emptyspot is an instance of Position and used in Board copy constructor, right ?

Comment: `tab` is a pointer. You allocate memory for its content with `new` and release it in destructor with `delete` **(you do, don't you?)**. If you simply did `tab(origin.tab)`, you would have two `tab`s pointing to the same memory location. After destruction of first object, second would use released memory and then tried to release it once again.

Comment: I'll go to create my destructors >_<

In the copy constructors, it says that this->tab = new int[this->nbline]; cannot convert int* to int**.

It also says that m is not declared (but i can replace it with nbline), so is memcpy (i included string.h)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, should be of course: `this->tab = new int*[this->nbline]`. I missed the `*`. Don't think you're bad - learning takes time.

Comment: It's working !!! \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/  Hopes are back !! THANKS A LOT !! I learnt quite a lot :o
Now i'll try to finish the methods for my tree and do that damn DepthFirstSearch !

Comment: Do you have any hints about how to do this ? ><

Answer (score 0):

As `state` is not in `Node`'s constructor initialization list, it will be created with its default constructor. The problem is, `Board` has no default constructor. To fix the problem, use the initialization list. This assumes that `Board` has an appropriate copy constructor.

```
Node::Node(const Board& tab)
    : state(tab)
{
}
```

I made the parameter const. I also removed the list assignment. I don't know what it means to assign NULL to a list, but if it's `std::list` then its default constructor will create it empty anyway.

Comment: Well, you're right, it's compiling now :o
std::list is empty by default construction ? Great

Comment: Can you help me with the copy constructor ? ._.

Is this ok ?  Board::Board(const Board& other) : tab(other.tab), nbline(other.nbline), nbcolumn(other.nbcolumn), emptyspot(other.emptyspot) {}

Comment: @Csi Trust me. It will be easier to learn vectors, and then not have to create a copy constructor, than to debug and get a custom one to work.